# extract the skills from one file after matching with datasets using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
inputfile=open('inputfile.txt', 'r')
cleaned_resume= inputfile.read()


def fetch_skills(cleaned_resume):
    with open('skillsdata.csv', 'r') as skills:
        skill_set=[]
        for skill in skills:
            if skill in cleaned_resume:
                print(skill)
                skill_set.append(skill)
    return skill_set
if __name__ == '__main__':
    skills = fetch_skills(cleaned_resume)

print(skills)
```

I want to extract the skills from "cleaned resume" after matching in skillsdata. But it's give the wrong output.

Comment: put text format of file

Comment: @pushpendrachauhan I also try with text file but return's same output

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
def fetch_skills(cleaned_resume=None):

    with open('skillsdata.csv', 'r') as skills:
        skill_set=[]
        for skill in skills:
            if skill in cleaned_resume:
                skill_set.append(skill)

    # Stripping newlines and tabs
    skill_set = [s.rstrip() for s in skill_set]

    return skill_set

if __name__ == '__main__':

    inputfile = open('inputfile.txt', 'r')
    cleaned_resume = inputfile.read()
    skills = fetch_skills(cleaned_resume=cleaned_resume)
    print(skills)
```

Comment: It gives the following output: '3d\n', '.com\n', '3d\n', 'SQL\n', 'A\n', 'AR\n', 'Application\n', 'CA\n', 'College\n', 'EB\n', 'IE\n', 'India\n', 'LAR\n', 'Management System\n', 'R\n', 'SQL\n', 'System\n', 'VM\n', 'X\n', '\n'

Comment: I edited the code a bit. Ran a test on my local machine. This works fine now. Please make sure you have the correct csv and text files in the same directory as the code.

Comment: Now it gives the following output: ['3d', '.com', '3d', 'SQL', 'A', 'AR', 'Application', 'CA', 'College', 'EB', 'IE', 'India', 'LAR', 'Management System', 'R', 'SQL', 'System', 'VM', 'X', ''

Comment: in inputfile i mention python django and so many skills this doesnot print all skills

Comment: Are you sure they match the skills in skillsdata.csv?

Comment: How i check this?

Comment: I think so it's matching

Comment: i found the issue: when word is in first position of line then it's match other wise not match, suppose In file we mention "Language known: python, c, c++" then it's not read but when i type python in another line then it's read and print

Comment: Alright! That was some pre-processing that needed to be done on your end. Hope I was able to help.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write in one file exactly one word in one line without "," from txt file

Comment: Ok send me an email at waqashamid722@gmail.com